# Solving a linear, 2nd order ODE IVP two different ways - one does not lead to solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

So I've been looking at solving linear, 2nd order ODEs of the form
$$ ay''+by'+cy=0$$
Now, if I solve the ODE
$$ y''+4y'+5y=0$$
I should be able to express the general solution either as
$$ y(t) = C_1 e^{(-2+i)t} + C_2 e^{(-2-i)t} $$
or, alternatively
$$ y(t) = e^{-2t}(c_1 \cos( t) + c_2 sin( t))$$
With $c_1 = C_1 + C_2$ and $c_2 = i(C_1 - C_2)$. Both formulations should, at least in theory, be equivalent since I simply derived the second from the first using Euler's formula. However, for the initial conditions $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=-5$, if one tries to solve for $C_1$ and $C_2$ using the first equation one gets a contradiction. On the other hand, solving for $c_1$ and $c_2$ using the second formulation gives the perfectly happy values of $c_1 = 2$ and $c_2 = -1$. What's going on here?

Comment: Please add more concretely what you got for the first variant. The resulting coefficient pair should be complex conjugate, so that one could also write $y(t)=2Re(C_1e^{(-2+i)t})$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y(t) = A e^{(-2+i)t} + Be^{(-2-i)t}$$
$$y'(t) = A(-2+i) e^{(-2+i)t} + B(-2-i)e^{(-2-i)t}$$
The initial conditions give ;
$$(A,B)=(1+\dfrac i 2,1-\dfrac i2)$$
For the second solution:
$$y(t) = e^{-2t}(c_1 \cos( t) + c_2 \sin( t))$$
$$y'(t) = -2e^{-2t}(c_1 \cos( t) + c_2 \sin( t))+ e^{-2t}(-c_1 \sin( t) + c_2 \cos( t))$$
The initial conditions give is:
$$(c_1,c_2)=(2,-1)$$
So that you have indeed:
$$c_1=A+B=2 \text { and } c_2=i(A-B)=i(i)=-1$$